# Image Magick is generating black images while converting pdf to jpg

Tags: imagemagick-convert

Image Magick version in use is 6.8.8.1.

Via command line on windows I am just trying to convert a *.pdf file into .jpg file using the following command

```
convert -density 100 -colorspace RGB "input.pdf" "output.jpg"
```

But the resulting output.jpg file is with a black image (there is no content). Any one out there could please guide on this ?

Answer (score 0):

When you open this PDF-file by using a text-editor and it's header contains something like this:

```
%PDF-1.5
%¦éÏÄ
4 0 obj
<</Length 5 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>stream
....
....
```

then you have to decode this flat-encoded stream first before you can convert it to an image.

To solve this problem:

1. You can use the GUI-Tool [pdftk free](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/), set your environment-path to the bin-folder within the pdftk-folder and execute:

   ```
   pdftk ENCODED_FILENAME.pdf output DECODED_FILENAME.pdf uncompress
   ```

   in the shell to deflate/unzip this file.
2. Create a new file that is not encoded or zipped.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set `alpha` flag to `off` in convert command.